# How To Sign Up A New User To My Website Using Facebook

Tags: database, facebook, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a relatively simple question that I am having trouble finding the answer to.  I want to set up a way for users to sign up for and log into my site using Facebook.  I have been through tutorials which show me processes I need to go through in order to enable my website to communicate with Facebook.

My question is: Once I can communicate with Facebook, how do I then sign a user up permanently on my site?  Do I pull information about the user from Facebook and just create a profile for them on my site using that information?  Wouldn't I need to then associate that user's unique Facebook ID with the profile I create for them on my website.  It seems like I will have to alter my databases in order to accommodate logging in through Facebook.  Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can authorize/reauthorize a User with Facebook even without any Database, but if you want to store data for the User (name, email, ...) or connect it to an existing User account in your Database, you can store the unique ID.

Use FB.login to authorize with Facebook and FB.getLoginStatus to refresh the User session and to check if a returning User authorized your App already. The User ID is in the callback response of those functions, for example:

```js
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        //user is authorized
        console.log(response.authResponse.userID);
    } else {
        //user is not authorized or not logged in on facebook
    }
});
```

Careful though, it is an "App Scoped ID" and only valid for one specific App. See changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Btw, here´s an article about Login with the JavaScrip SDK: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/